# Not able to Click on the Drop down and wait for element also fail for drop down ID in IFrame with JavaScript

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, test-automation-framework, testing-framework

I am unable to click on this dropdown.

I tried selecting the dropdown and javascript click and normal click. Waiting for this element to be present also fails.

Please provide the solution for the same.

[image]

Below is the code for waitForElement, typeAction etc. 
Locator type, LocatorName, and data comes from excel file. I have created a hybrid framework.

```
public static void waitForElement(WebDriver driver, String locator_Type, String locator_Value) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30 );
    if (locator_Type.equalsIgnoreCase("id"))
    {
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(locator_Value)));
     // dropdown.click();
    }
    else
        if (locator_Type.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath"))
        {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(locator_Value)));
        }
            else
                if (locator_Type.equalsIgnoreCase("classname")) {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className(locator_Value)));
        }
        }
    public static void typeAction(WebDriver driver, String locator_Type, String locator_Value, String data) {
    if (locator_Type.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
        driver.findElement(By.id(locator_Value)).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id(locator_Value)).sendKeys(data);

    }
    if (locator_Type.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath")) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator_Type)).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator_Value)).sendKeys(data);
    }
}
    public static void dropDown(WebDriver driver, String locatorType, String locatorValue, String data) {
    if (locatorType.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id(locatorValue))).selectByVisibleText(data);

    } else if (locatorType.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath")) {
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(locatorValue))).selectByVisibleText(data);
    }

public static void clickScript (WebDriver driver, String Locator_Type, String Locator_Value)


        {
            if (Locator_Type.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
                WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(Locator_Value));
                JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

            } else if (Locator_Type.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath")) {
                WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(Locator_Value));
                JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Posting the source code of the drop down may help people understand your issue

Comment: public static void dropDown(WebDriver driver, String locatorType, String locatorValue, String data) {
        if (locatorType.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.id(locatorValue))).selectByVisibleText(data);

        } else if (locatorType.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath")) {
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(locatorValue))).selectByVisibleText(data);
        }